# Examine environment variables on the stack

Tags: c, environment-variables, gdb, stack, x86-64

I know that environment variables are above the stack in memory, and I want to list them or at least be able to see them through examining the stack using `gdb`. First I take the address of the stack pointer but since the variables are placed above the stack, how do I know by how much I should increment the address?

```
(gdb) info register rsp
rsp            0x7fffffffdf48      0x7fffffffdf48
(gdb) x/32s $rsp + 0x(mmm..)
```

An example I saw while browsing the web was

```
x/32s $rsp + 0x240 // Why 0x240, exactly?
```

I think I misunderstood smth.

Comment: Their location on the stack is only relevant at process startup, in `_start`.  Nothing else has any guaranteed offset to them, just an implementation detail how much stack space CRT startup code used between `_start` and `main`.  Unless you're writing an exploit against a certain compiled binary, then you can find out by trial and error for a given number of command-line args.  Otherwise just look at the `envp` global var, or `main`'s third arg.

Comment: @PeterCordes `envp` is just the conventional name of `main`'s third arg. `environ` is the global you're thinking of.

Comment: @PeterCordes we have to rely that `main`'s third argument is defined, don't we?

Comment: @Roi: Yeah, but it will be on systems that follow the x86-64 System V ABI for process startup stack state, unless you're writing your own `_start`.  In which case you should point GDB to that stack frame so you can find the initial RSP and work from there just like `_start` did to find argc, argv, and envp.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that environment variables are above the stack in memory,

It is Linux implementation detail that `envp` vector (along with `argv`) and its elements are stored in the stack memory of the *main* thread (only). [System V Application Binary Interface AMD64 with LP64 and ILP32 Programming Models](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/x86-64-psABI-1.0.pdf) (see Figure 3.9: Initial Process Stack) requires that executable entry point `_start` gets `%rsp` which points to `argc`, followed by `argv` vector, followed by `envp` vector, all in the *main* thread stack. How much of the stack is consumed by `_start` (normally implemented by your language/compiler run-time) when it invokes `main` is an implementation detail which depends on the version and the vendor of the run-time, the ABI is only concerned with entry point `_start`.

An advanced defender can start other threads from the main thread and then terminate the main thread without terminating the process. This way, no thread stack contains the environment. It can also wipe its `argv` and `envp` and/or the elements the vectors point to, so that they become unavailable in the process address space. The latter, however, doesn't affect `/proc/self/environ` or `/proc/self/cmdline` maintained by the kernel.

The exact location is in `envp` argument to `main`. The C standard doesn't require anything beyond that, e.g. *the thread stack* is an implementation detail.

> how do I know by how much I should increment the address?

That may depend on options the code was compiled with and the current stacktrace.

Ask `x` to display a larger array to see the environment variables:

```
x/2048s $rsp
```

Comment: Well displaying a larger array isn't a solution ig but it works. I was curious on whether I can tell the exact location or not, but thanks.

Comment: The exact location is in `envp` argument to `main`. The C standard doesn't require anything beyond that, like _the stack_.

Comment: Yeah it seems not to work anymore even with a larger array. This is a lot harder then I thought It'd be, but I think I got the concept. Thank you Maxim.

Comment: I think y'all didn't understand my question and that's my fault. I want to get the _addresses_ of these variables in run-time with `gdb`.

Comment: @SayNoToWhiteBoys My misunderstanding. I wonder why you need the pointer to the environment variables?

Comment: It's just part of my binary exploitation journey and I learn how to use env variables as an exploitation method in which we have a shellcode as a variable.

Comment: Think of it as a binary that you **don't** know its source code and all you want to achieve is the _binary_'s env variables **using** _gdb_ by examining the stack pointer. That's literally it but now I see it's much more than this normal task so I will just drop it here since we don't understand each other.

Comment: @SayNoToWhiteBoys Let's imagine you inferred that `envp` is at `offset` from `%rsp`. You want to overwrite function's return address with stackoverflow to point to your shellcode in an environment variable, let's suppose you succeed in that. Then you have a problem that the code was compiled with `-fstack-protector` or CPU uses a shadow return stack to protect from exactly such a stack corruption, the most common attack vector, so that your stackoverflow just terminates the process. Next, the stack isn't executable, `SIGBUS`... IMO, your stackoverflow attack vector requires an ancient target.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

> I want to get the addresses of these variables in run-time with gdb.

That's trivial: step to the `main` level in GDB, print the value of the `RBP` register, and then use your understanding of stack layout (see below).

Example:

```
env -i FOO=ABC BAR=DEF HOME=/tmp gdb -q --args ./a.out foo bar baz
Reading symbols from ./a.out...
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x11b8: file t.c, line 6.
Starting program: /tmp/a.out foo bar baz

Temporary breakpoint 1, main (argc=4, argv=0x7fffffffedb8) at t.c:6
6         printf("Argument vector:\n");

(gdb) p/x $rbp
$1 = 0x7fffffffecc0
(gdb) x/8gx $rbp
0x7fffffffecc0: 0x0000000000000000      0x00007ffff7df17fd
0x7fffffffecd0: 0x00007fffffffedb8      0x00000004f7fca000
0x7fffffffece0: 0x00005555555551a9      0x00007fffffffef79
0x7fffffffecf0: 0x00005555555552c0      0x9a3bd5580a4c103c
```

Above, you can see the `&argv[0] == 0x00007fffffffedb8` as the 3rd word on the stack (the other two are the previous value of `RBP` and the return address). Use the first example code below to recover complete `argv[]` and `envp[]`.

---

> how do I know by how much I should increment the address?

If you are in `main()`, on Linux, you can know the *exact* [layout of stack](http://asm.sourceforge.net/articles/startup.html), and can examine `argc`, `argv[]` and `envp[]` using e.g. this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int j;
  printf("Argument vector:\n");
  for (j = 0; ; j++) {
    if (argv[j] == NULL) break;
    printf("%2d: %p %s\n", j, argv[j], argv[j]);
  }
  printf("Environment vector:\n");
  for (j++; ; j++) {
    if (argv[j] == NULL) break;
    printf("%2d: %p %s\n", j, argv[j], argv[j]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc -g t.c && env -i FOO=ABC BAR=DEF HOME=/tmp ./a.out foo bar baz
Argument vector:
 0: 0x7ffd39e05fc2 ./a.out
 1: 0x7ffd39e05fca foo
 2: 0x7ffd39e05fce bar
 3: 0x7ffd39e05fd2 baz
Environment vector:
 5: 0x7ffd39e05fd6 FOO=ABC
 6: 0x7ffd39e05fde BAR=DEF
 7: 0x7ffd39e05fe6 HOME=/tmp
```

You could also leverage the fact that GLIBC actually passes `envp[]` to `main()` as the 3rd argument:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
  printf("Environment vector:\n");
  for (int j= 0; ; j++) {
    if (envp[j] == NULL) break;
    printf("%2d: %p %s\n", j, envp[j], envp[j]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

```
Environment vector:
 0: 0x7ffdef096fd6 FOO=ABC
 1: 0x7ffdef096fde BAR=DEF
 2: 0x7ffdef096fe6 HOME=/tmp
```

If you are *not* in `main()`, and can't have `main()` save `&argv[0]` in a global, then things get trickier.

You can parse `/proc/self/maps` to figure out stack boundaries, and examine the stack that way (see "stack set by kernel" section [here](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/linux/hh/stack-layout.html)).

Comment: Why not just accept `envp` argument to `main`?

Comment: Well thanks but I need to find the addresses of a program's env variables in run-time.

Comment: "I need to find the addresses of a program's env variables in run-time." -- the examples above _do_ find the addresses at runtime.

Comment: @EmployedRussian Well after your edit, it really do find. but that's not what I want either, see my comments on Maxim's answer. But hey, I never knew that `main` accepts third argument `envp` so thanks for that!